# google maps - get state name by city or zip input

Tags: google-maps, zipcode, city

how is it possible to get the name of the state by entering a zip or city name?

for example:

city name: buffalo

get state name: new york

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to try to get the info. For example see a [Geocode request for buffalo](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=buffalo&sensor=false) and in the response the administrative_area_level_1 is "New York"